# How can I put a buffer into dired mode?

Tags: emacs, dired

I've created a list of file names, and done some qualification of the ones I want.
Now I'd like to run "ls -l" on that list, and put the result in a dired-mode buffer.
Right now I'm running find-grep-dired to get files which have matches to a
regular expression.  But the find command takes minutes to run in my environment,
and I have to run it multiple times for each of several patterns.  I'm too
impatient to wait for the results.

I tried just reading the ls -l value into a buffer and then executing "dired-mode".  But "dired-mode" is not a function, more's the pity.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand what are your "qualifications" and why you speak about `ls -l` but then about grepping. Anyway, `helm-grep` is said to be faster than original emacs' grep and `ack` is considered the fastest of all: see https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki and https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ack

Comment: I think this thread may help: http://superuser.com/a/807979/206164  Essentially, you can create a list and open a dired buffer with a variety of unrelated files and directories -- e.g., `(dired '("*my-dired-buffer*" "DIR1" "FILE1" "DIR2" "FILE2" "FILE3"))`

Comment: Dired-mode uses `ls`, so there is no reason to run `ls` beforehand -- just set the `dired-listing-switches` to your liking -- they can be let-bound for the duration of your function, and your buffer (listed in the previous comment) will contain the files and directories of your choosing with the corresponding `ls` details.

Comment: Yes, I think the OP is asking about how to get Dired to show a list of files that you provide it (regardless of how that list might be created - in this case by using `ls`). If so, the question that @lawlist cited should be relevant.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have the answer.  The lawlist comment was relevant, but I solved my problem by running "find-dired" with command equal to "-prune -exec cat myfile.txt \;".  I suppose I didn't really need the -prune.  Drew is right, I had to generate the file list independently, for a previous step in my workflow.

Comment: It turns out that the -prune, which was a mistake, is actually necessary.  I don't know why, but if I don't put -prune at the beginning, files get listed many times.  I think it may execute the command for every file or directory?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the answer to the question is:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `virtual-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you have a buffer containing the output of `ls -lR <dir>` then this command will convert it into a dired buffer.

The `-R` argument means that the path to each of the listed directories is included, and Emacs will pick that up as the default value when it prompts you for the directory path.

Of course you don't always *want* a recursive listing; but if you have just a single directory listing via `ls -l` then that header line isn't included, and you'll need to enter the directory manually at the prompt.

Of course you can easily generate that line yourself to work around the problem:

```
printf "%s:\n" $(pwd) && ls -l
```

**Edit:** I didn't notice that this was part of the `dired-x` library, which isn't auto-loaded. See the manual:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(dired-x)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: That's odd.  I have emacs 24.3.1, but I don't have virtual-dired.  Other than that detail, this and the documentation in the emacs wiki seem to imply that this is what I needed all along.